How to dynamically check and infer form submission types based on a form structure?
I'm working on a form validation feature in TypeScript where forms consist of multiple sections, and each section has a specific type for its answer (e.g., a string, number, or array). I would like to dynamically check if a form submission matches the expected structure and then infer the correct types for the submission data for use in the rest of the function.
Example Structure:
type Section = 'name' | 'age' | 'nicknames';

type Form = readonly Section[];

// Map sections to their answer types
type AnswerForSection<Section> = Section extends 'age'
  ? number
  : Section extends 'name'
  ? string
  : Section extends 'nicknames'
  ? string[]
  : never;

// Expected submission shape for a form
type ValidFormSubmission<F extends Form> = {
  [Section in F[number]]: AnswerForSection<Section>;
};


// Examples of forms
const form1 = ['name', 'age'] as const;
const form2 = ['name', 'nicknames'] as const;

type Form1SubmissionType = ValidFormSubmission<typeof form1>;
// { name: string, age: number } - This is what I expect


I want to write a function checkFormAnswers that:

Takes in a form and a submission.
First checks if the submission matches the form's expected shape.
If the check passes, it should let TypeScript infer the types of the form submission (e.g., the age field should be inferred as number).

I have defined a type guard to check if the submission for a form matches the expected structure, and have added that type guard to the top of the checkFormAnswers function:
function satisfiesForm<F extends Form>(
  form: F,
  submissionData: Record<string, any>,
): submissionData is ValidFormSubmission<F> {
  * Implementation details not important for this question *
}

function checkFormAnswers<F extends Form>(
  form: F,
  submission: Record<string, any>,
) {
  if (satisfiesForm(form, submission)) {
    form.forEach((question) => {
      if (question === 'age') {
      // I want TS to infer that submission has an 'age' field because the form does
      // and the submission satisfies the form
        const age = submission['age']; 
        console.log('Age is:', age); // I want TS to infer that age is a number
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.error('Invalid form submission');
  }
}

But Typescript doesn't seem to infer the types correctly after the guard. I get the following ts error:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"age"' can't be used to index type 'ValidFormSubmission<F>'. Property 'age' does not exist on type 'ValidFormSubmission<F>'.
I can get rid of this error by editing checkFormAnswers to:
function checkFormAnswers<F extends Form>(
  form: F,
  submission: Record<string, any>,
) {
  if (satisfiesForm(form, submission)) {
    form.forEach((question) => {
      const key = question as F[number];
      if (key === 'age') {
        const age = submission[key];
        console.log('Age is:', age);
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.error('Invalid form submission');
  }
}

But then age is inferred as string | number | string[]
Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do here?
Edit: Follow Up
My real form structure is a bit more complex:
interface BaseSection {
  readonly id: string;
}
interface TextSection extends BaseSection {
  type: 'text';
}
interface NumericSection extends BaseSection {
  type: 'numeric';
}
...
type Section = TextSection | NumericSection | MultipleChoiceSection;

type Form = readonly Section[];

type AnswerForSection<S extends Section> = S['type'] extends 'numeric'
  ? number
  : S['type'] extends 'text'
  ? string
  : S['type'] extends 'multiple-choice'
  ? string[]
  : never;

type AnswerForSections<Sections extends readonly Section[]> = {
  [K in Sections[number] as K['id']]: AnswerForSection<K>;
};

type ValidFormSubmission<F extends Form> = AnswerForSections<F>;

const form1 = [
  { id: 'name', type: 'text' },
  { id: 'age', type: 'numeric' },
] as const;

const form2 = [
  { id: 'name', type: 'text' },
  { id: 'favorite-foods', type: 'multiple-choice' },
] as const;

type Form1SubmissionType = ValidFormSubmission<typeof form1>;
// {
//   name: string;
//   age: number;
// }

Is it possible to infer the type of this?
Playground

The rule of generics that a generic parameter should be used more than once.
If you follow the rule with
function checkFormAnswers(
  form: Form,
  submission: Record<string, any>,
) 

then it works fine: Playground
The problem with the generic could be (I'm not an expert) that you EXTEND it from Form thus you could provide a BROADER type. For example ['name'] & ['test'] extends Form. It's not a meaningful but valid type. So your index signature [Section in F[number]] with this broader type doesn't allow TS to infer link between property keys and their values, thus age = string | number | string[].
But I suggest to apply more atomic/precise typing and my rule and intuition is not to pass array types as generic parameters. Rather pass array element types. Simplifying the overall code gives us:
type AnswerForSection = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  nicknames: string[]
}

type Section = keyof AnswerForSection;

type Form = readonly Section[];

// Expected submission shape for a form
type ValidFormSubmission<S extends Section> = {
  [Section in S]: AnswerForSection[Section]
};

// Examples of forms
const form1 = ['name', 'age'] as const;
const form2 = ['name', 'nicknames'] as const;

type Form1SubmissionType = ValidFormSubmission<typeof form1[number]>;
// { name: string, age: number } - This is what I expect

declare function satisfiesForm<F extends Form>(
  form: Form,
  submissionData: Record<string, any>,
): submissionData is ValidFormSubmission<F[number]>

function checkFormAnswers<F extends Form>(
  form: F,
  submission: Record<string, any>,
) {
  if (satisfiesForm(form, submission)) {
    form.forEach((question) => {
      if (question === 'age') {
      // I want TS to infer that submission has an 'age' field because the form does
      // and the submission satisfies the form
        const age = submission[question]; 
        console.log('Age is:', age); // I want TS to infer that age is a number
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.error('Invalid form submission');
  }
}

which works fine: Playground
Since we use Section as a generic parameter for ValidFormSubmission and it's a string literal union, seems TS can use it for the type guard and indexing the resulting type guard's type.
UPDATE
The closest I've managed to achieve:
Playground
interface BaseSection {
  readonly id: string;
}
interface TextSection extends BaseSection {
  type: 'text';
}
interface NumericSection extends BaseSection {
  type: 'numeric';
}
interface MultipleChoiceSection extends BaseSection {
  type: 'multiple-choice';
}
type Section = TextSection | NumericSection | MultipleChoiceSection;

type Form = readonly Section[];

type AnswerForSection = {
  numeric: number,
  text: string,
  'multiple-choice': string[]
}

type AnswerForSections<S extends Section> = {
  [K in S['id']]: AnswerForSection[S extends {id: K} ? S['type']: never];
};

const form1 = [
  { id: 'name', type: 'text' },
  { id: 'age', type: 'numeric' },
] as const;

const form2 = [
  { id: 'name', type: 'text' },
  { id: 'favorite-foods', type: 'multiple-choice' },
] as const;

type Form1SubmissionType = AnswerForSections<typeof form1[number]>;
// {
//   name: string;
//   age: number;
// }

type Form2SubmissionType = AnswerForSections<typeof form2[number]>;

declare function satisfiesForm<S extends Section>(
  section: S,
  submissionData: Readonly<Record<string, any>>,
): submissionData is AnswerForSections<S>;

function checkFormAnswers<F extends Form>(form: F, submission: Record<string, any>) {
  for(const section of form){
    if (section.type === 'numeric' && satisfiesForm(section, submission)) {
        const answer = submission[section.id]; // I want TS to infer that is this a number
    }
  }
}


Thank you for the answer. Removing the extra Generic solved this. I realize that I over-simplified my example in attempt to make it minimally reproducible. My actual Form structure is this `interface BaseSection {
readonly id: string;
}
interface TextSection extends BaseSection {
type: 'text';
}
interface NumericSection extends BaseSection {
type: 'numeric';
}
...
type Section = TextSection | NumericSection | MultipleChoiceSection;
type Form = readonly Section[];
`
Would you mind taking a look at the playground link I added to my question?

@GrahamDom updated the answer

Thanks, this is very close. I'm going to leave it open for now

@GrahamDom the problem that we need use an object as a generic param and typescript is weak in handling correlation between object props ans tuple members afaik

So this could be impossible to solve it seems

@GrahamDom i am not an expert to claim that 100%
